# How to transform this time series data?

Tags: time-series

[image]

[image]

[image]

Given in these plots above is the US unemply. Data since 1948 till recently a month back. I tried using a log and difference transform to make the data look more stationary. This is what I get as the final result. This looks more squished in a bit more stationary looking. But the model I end up getting is much more complicated than wanted. Is there are possibilities I may look into to see if I can come up with a better model? I need to keep the data as is meaning I do not want to get rid of portions. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the shocks that are apparent in the time series, I don't think differencing, log-differencing and similar simple transformations will be of use. You'll likely need more complicated econometric models. A quick search reveals many papers dealing with this very topic, e.g. [(Ghosh, 2008)](http://capone.mtsu.edu/jee/fall2008/4-MS608-2ndrevision.pdf) or [(Hutton, 2009)](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05112009-172919/unrestricted/HuttonMastersThesis.pdf) might be good starting points.